# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object while using a hugging face model

Tags: python, typeerror, huggingface

I am trying to us DiffusionPipeline from hugging face to generate Image from text but the following error is being generated:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
The traceback:
 File "c:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\Desktop\Artificial Intelligence\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\diffusers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .pipelines import DDIMPipeline, DDPMPipeline, KarrasVePipeline, LDMPipeline, PNDMPipeline, ScoreSdeVePipeline
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .latent_diffusion import LDMTextToImagePipeline
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\latent_diffusion\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .pipeline_latent_diffusion import LDMBertModel, LDMTextToImagePipeline
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\latent_diffusion\pipeline_latent_diffusion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from transformers.activations import ACT2FN
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import dependency_versions_check
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .generic import (
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\generic.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .import_utils import is_flax_available, is_tf_available, is_torch_available, is_torch_fx_proxy
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 376, in <module>
    torch_version = version.parse(importlib_metadata.version("torch"))
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 49, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\Users\BHAVYA SHAH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__ 
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Help to solve this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: `python -m pip install torch`?